# How to run unittests on Google App Engine app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was reading [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting) guide on Google's app engine page, and created the following code to test my submission handler:

```
class CreatePostsTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',Submit)])
        self.testapp = webtest.TestApp(app)

    def testSubmit(self):   
        response = self.testapp.post('/',{'title':'testpost','body':'this is a body'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_int,200)
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but how do I run the unittest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in one of the articles linked to by the guide you where reading.

See the last section of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Introducing_the_Python_testing_utilities